# Reuse values in knockoutjs data-bind

Tags: knockout.js

I have `span` (inside `foreach` loop) in which I'm using `data-bind` for `text` and `css` properties

```
<!-- ko foreach: items -->
<span data-bind="text: $root.calculateText($data), css: { someClass: $root.calculateText($data) == 'someText'} "></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I would like to reuse calculated value for `text` and not calculate it second time for css.

Is there any ability in knockout for it?

One option that I thought about is inside of method `calculateText` add to item property `calculateText` and reuse it in css. But hope to find more efficient solution.

Comment: You'll need to give us a good repro including the View Models and the `calculateText` code. There are *many* ways to go about this problem, and the solution depends on that bit of context.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a computed observable which uses the root its calculateText method. You can use the root by passing it as the parent for the child objects.

I've created a JsFiddle which demonstrates this:
http://jsfiddle.net/YannickArien/BuH7N/398/

For example;

```
var Item = function(name, parent) {
   var _self = this;

   _self.name = ko.observable(name); 
   _self.parent = parent; 
   _self.yourComputed = ko.computed(function() {
       return _self.parent.calculateText(_self);        
   }, this);
};

var ViewModel = function() {
   var _self = this;

   _self.calculateText = function(item) {
       return item.name(); // Or whatever you want to do here.
   }

   _self.items = ko.observableArray([
       new Item("one", _self),
       new Item("two", _self),
       new Item("three", _self)
       ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

For the sake of completeness you could ignore the computed part and do something like the following, but it depends on the exact requirement. The following 2 lines are the only changes compared to the previous version.

```
_self.yourComputed = _self.parent.calculateText(_self);

<span data-bind="text: yourComputed, css: { someClass: yourComputed == 'two'} "></span>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, though appropriateness depends on OP's actual scenario. (Small bug in your SO post though, the second `yourComputed` should be executed as a function. The jsfiddle has the correct version.)